# Gibt es einen Algorithmus zur grammatikalischen Analyse für "sie" versus "Sie"?

Tags: capitalization, personal-pronoun, resource

Ich vertippe mich ständig, dass ich das kleingeschriebene *sie* statt dem großgeschriebenen *Sie* verwende. Automatisch Tipps zu geben ist sicher schwer, aber vielleicht gibt es ja schon automatische Werkzeuge, die das können?

Comment: Es gibt keinen grammatikalischen Unterschied, das Tool müsste den Text also „verstehen“. Sicher eine theoretisch interessante Aufgabe, aber es würde mich wundern, wenn es da etwas Praktikables gäbe.

Comment: Ist das so? "Wenn **Sie** vier plus vier rechnen, ..." vs. "Dort stehen Vieren. Wenn sie addiert werden, ...". Welche grammatikalische Rolle haben hier "sie" und "Sie"? Ok, ich habe hier einen Passiv- und einen Aktivsatz, wahrscheinlich nicht vergleichbar. Gibt es Beispiele mit jeweils gleichen Rollen für beides? Wenn ja, dann meinte ich wohl eher *semantisch*. Dann wird es sicher schwer, das stimmt. Aber ein paar Ansätze gibt es glaube ich schon.

Comment: *Sie erzählten, dass [sS]ie [sS]ie getroffen habe.* - Not even a human can detect the correct form here without context.

Comment: Genauer gesagt ist "sie" im Plural nicht von der Andrede zu unterscheiden. Ich kann zu Dir sagen, "wenn du addiert wirst, ...", was grammatikalisch korrekt nur wahrscheinlich ohne Sinn ist. Sieze ich Dich, dann wird daraus "wenn Sie addiert werden, ...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schon der Beispielsatz "Wenn Sie vier plus vier rechnen, ..." zeigt, dass beide Formen von *sie* grammatikalisch passen. Es kommt also auf den restlichen Kontext des Textes an, ob es sich um *Sie* oder *sie* handelt. Das kann kein automatisches Werkzeug lösen.

Comment: Ich erinnere mich an eine Unterhaltung, bei der "sie" gemeint war, ein Zuhörer aber "Sie" verstanden hat, weil dies noch nicht einmal mit dem Kontext klar war.

Comment: Genau. Das automatische Werkzeug müsste dann rückfragen - wie ein Mensch auch in solch einem Fall.